# How to connect from lambda to AWS RDS Proxy in python?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I try to connect to a MySQL RDS database and getting a timeout error:

> "Can't connect to MySQL server on
> 'XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (timed out)")

The AWS Lambda can connect to AWS RDS Secrets, but looks like no with AWS RDS Proxy. The lambda in a VPC. Here is the code i using on Python:

```
def connect_mysql(secret, pipeline):
    import pymysql
    import pymysql.cursors

    dbname = pipeline["aws"]["rds"]["dbname"]
    user = secret["username"]
    host = secret["host"]
    password = secret["password"]

    try:

        # Connect to the database
        connection = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                                    user=user,
                                    password=password,
                                    database=dbname,
                                    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

        logger.info(f"Connected to: {dbname}")
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        logger.warning(f"Error connecting AWS RDS")

    return  connection
```

Comment: You don't connect to the RDS database directly. You connect to the proxy endpoint. Which does `pipeline["aws"]["rds"]["dbname"]` represent?

Comment: Thanks, The endpoint i getting from secrets is saved on -> secret["host"], Should I change it? Because `pipeline["aws"]["rds"]["dbname"]` represents the name of the database on the AWS RDS.

Comment: It needs to be the [RDS Proxy endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html#rds-proxy-endpoints). Something like endpoint-demo-reader.endpoint.proxy-demo.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com.

Comment: How did you pass RDS' credentials into the python code? Is it done by lambda?